# Bootstrap sidebar on both sides of screen without collapse

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I've been trying to get this to work for awhile now, but I seem to just keep breaking what I already have in place.

I'm trying to design an interface that has a middle content area and then on either side a large button to either precede or to go back.

In bootstrap I have tried using the `col-md` classes, but when re-sizing the browser the sections pile on top of each other, not something I want to happen.

I have also tried having the main content area and then on either side have a `pull-right` and a `pull-left`, but this seems to have the same re-sizing effect.

Is there anyway of doing this without having the elements pile on top of each other?

Comment: can you provide a fiddle or bootply which shows the relevant code?

Answer (score 0):

you may wanna use `col-xs-??` instead ;)

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="col-xs-2"><a href="#">Back</a></div>
  <div class="col-xs-8">The Content</div>
  <div class="col-xs-2"><a href="#">Forth</a></div>
</div>
```

Comment: it's still the same issue, of them collapsing on top of each other when the browser is reduced.

Comment: can u provide a simple jsfiddle? Im sure we can fix this.